# PHP converting PCRE unicode sequence to normal utf-8 string

Tags: php, unicode, utf-8, pcre

Is it possible within PHP convert unicode PCRE sequence ( like `\x{2f}`, `\x{3251}` ) to string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [html_entity_decode](http://php.net/html_entity_decode) its possible

```
function cb($a){
        $num = $a[1];
        $dec = hexdec($num);
        return "&#$dec;";
}
$ent = preg_replace_callback("/\\\\x\{([\da-z]+)\}/i", 'cb', "\x{2f}, \x{3251}");
$ustr = html_entity_decode($ent, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

**Sample:** http://ideone.com/fDNGM